# Destroy a document not working using ruby on rails 4 with mongoDB Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

Creating,querying,updating are working from the same database in my rails application.But,destroy is not deleting the document from the mongoDB.
here is my destroy method:

```
def destroy
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.destroy
  redirect_to @article
end
```

Without Deleting always it is redirecting me to article page.
Here *Article* is my model name.
*articles* is my database collection name.
Using **Mongoid** to build mongoDB queries.

Below is code for link to delete
`<%= link_to 'Delete', article_path(article),:method => :delete,
data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>`

However,
 `db.articles.remove({"title":"somename"})`
can delete document with *title* as "somename".

Comment: Have you tried the [**delete**](https://github.com/mongomapper/mongomapper/blob/b965105ea203368234636df21c64f05358a467fb/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb#L43-57) method `@article.delete`?

Comment: Tried `@article.delete`  
It is redirecting me to article page without deleting.Same thing happened with `@article.destroy` also.

Answer (score 0):

Changing Coffee script version solved this problem!I thought this solution is worth sharing!
In gem file changed coffee script gem file to:
`gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'`
and run bundle with command as:
`gem install coffee-script-source` 
and run
`bundle update coffee-script-source` 
and bundle install again to change the coffee script version.
And the destroy method worked as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to destroy the element against the DB instead of the object you just created. This said, try to **avoid** `@article.destroy`, instead use:

```
Article.find(params[:id]).destroy
```

The first way you are only destroying the object which is not the node on DB, remind it is only a representation of the given node.

Hope this works! have a nice day!

Comment: But he solved the problem simply by updating coffee script?